# get specific lines from File1, others from File2 and print them in File3

Tags: grep, sed, awk

I'm trying to get specific lines from File1, and others from File2 and print them in File3 (in consecutive order).

Let's say I need lines 1 and 3 from File1 and Lines 6 and 8 from File 2, then print them in File3.

I came up with this form:

```
grep -H 'x*' File1.txt File2.txt | sed '/File1.txt:[13]/d;/File2.txt:[68]/d;s/[^:]*://' > File3.txt
```

This deletes the 'unwanted' lines and print them in a third file, which works well for few lines, but with more lines it mixes them up in a weird way in the output file. In this example line 1 and 3 is: [13]), but I'll have hundreds or more lines, so I don't know how to separate different lines in the brackets (I know a 'comma' in between doesn't work).

I included [File1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqMDM.png) and [File2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wby27.png) (to give an idea of my files). For instance, I'd need lines 19 to 40 from File1, and lines 9 to 18 from File2 printed in File3 (same order). Is there any other way of doing this that you can suggest?

I'd appreciate it.

Steph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick answer (others can feel free to edit to add details):

```
(sed -n 19,40p File1; sed -n 9,18p File2) > File3
```

`-n` tells `sed` to not automatically print all input lines, then `X,Yp` tells it to print lines X to Y, inclusive. The `(command1; command2)` construct "joins" both commands into one for the purpose of output redirection.

Comment: Yes, this works, I just have to give the number of the lines according to the file, not to the value in the first column. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @pollux7 `sed` is capable of selecting lines based on a pattern match rather than a line number - however that's not what you asked. OTOH is you want to select lines on the basis of an arithmetic column value that's a job for Awk or Perl

Comment: I can make it work for my purposes that's what I meant, but thanks a lot for the clarification, I'll keep it in mind for other cases in the future.